# Is it permissible for dApps to use 'EOS' in their brand name?

Tags: dapp, dac

Are there any trademark restrictions on naming dApps EOSbook, EOScabs, EOSfood etc? If the answer is no, then isn't it possible that somebody out there might go out and obtain a copyright for 'EOS'? Or has B1 already made arrangements to eliminate such a situation?